# Swipe large images with no delay

Tags: android, photoswipe

I developed a gallery app with swipe images function (drag to the left/right and a new full screen image is appear).
The problem is that I did not succeed to overcome the small delay of large images until they appear (whatsapp images - no problem, with camera images it is not smooth like in the build-in gallery app).
I tried several method to re size/decode the image but still there is a delay.

My code:

**`FullScreenImageAdapter.java`**

```
public class FullScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Activity _activity;
private ArrayList<String> _imagePaths;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 800;

// constructor
public FullScreenImageAdapter(Activity activity,
                              ArrayList<String> imagePaths) {
    this._activity = activity;
    this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this._imagePaths.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imgDisplay;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container,
            false);

    imgDisplay = (ImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);

    Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(_imagePaths.get(position),1000,1000);

    imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);

    return viewLayout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(String path, int reqWidth,
                                                 int reqHeight) {

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    return bmp;
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
                                        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

}

**FullScreenViewActivity.java**

```
public class FullScreenViewActivity extends Activity{

private FullScreenImageAdapter adapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;
int selectedFilePosition;
String imageFolder;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen_view);

    //geting the selected image from the intent
    /* Getting ImageURI from Gallery from Main Activity */
    Uri selectedImgUri = getIntent().getData();
    if (selectedImgUri!=null) {
        imageFolder = getRealPathFromURI(this, selectedImgUri);
    }

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    adapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(FullScreenViewActivity.this, getFilePaths(imageFolder));

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // displaying selected image first
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(selectedFilePosition);
}

// Reading file paths from SDCard
public ArrayList<String> getFilePaths(String selectedFilePath) {
    ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();

    File file = new File(selectedFilePath);
    File directory = file.getParentFile();

    // check for directory
    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        // getting list of file paths
        File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();

        // Check for count
        if (listFiles.length > 0) {
                // loop through all files
                for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {
                    // get file path
                    String filePath = listFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();
                    //set position if this is the required image to show
                    if (filePath.equals(selectedFilePath)) {
                        selectedFilePosition = i;
                        // Add image path to array list
                        filePaths.add(filePath);
                    }
                }
        }

    }
    return filePaths;
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

To improve performance you need another thread to load it async. Here are the third party libraries ([Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)) that you can use when working with large images.

Answer (score 1):

I also would use Picasso for loading Images into the ImageView. [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) caches the Image if it is Loaded once. To preload some elements you can use the Consumner/Producer Pattern! Example [here](https://dzone.com/articles/producer-consumer-design).

Comment: I implemented Picasso and performances are slightly better but I think that the problem is the amount of images that are preloaded.

Comment: Currently the viewpager is loading the required image and preloading another 2 images (one to the left and second to the right of the required image). Swiping to the preloaded image is responsive but the problem occurs when swiping several times to the same direction. Is there a method to auto preload more than 2 images by the viewpager?